# could not get access to my api in next js 14

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, next.js

i followed all the conventions and have written my api but on the client it not reaching the api endpoint.On the browser it says 500 internal server error.and the problem comes from the fetch api part on the client.shows on the web server's side when trying to fulfill a request. This doesn't provide specific details about what went wrong, but it signifies that something unexpected occurred while the server was processing a request, and it was unable to complete the request as a result.

[API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHKZN.png)
[CLIENT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiOdm.png)
my API:

This looks for to me by the way.open for correction

```
export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
const description = await request.json();
console.log(description);

    // const createAbout = await prisma.about.create({
    //     data: { desn cription }
    // })
    
    // if (!createAbout)
    //     return NextResponse.json(createAbout, { status: 404 })
    return NextResponse.json({ description, status: 404 });

};
```

```
"use client"
import { Button, Input, Textarea } from "@nextui-org/react";
import React, { FormEvent, useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

const adminAbout = () => {

  const router = useRouter()
  const [data, setData] = useState()
  async function handleSubmit(e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    e.preventDefault()
    try {
      const formData = new FormData(e.currentTarget)
      const data = await fetch('/api/about', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
      }).then(res => res.json)

    } catch (error) {
      console.error("error occured during the process!!!")
    }
    setData(data)
    router.refresh()


  }
  return (
    <section className="mx-auto py-10 p-5 flex flex-col max-w-lg">
      <div className="">
        <h1 className="py-5 font-bold">About Form</h1>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default adminAbout;
```

Comment: you are trying to fetch data from same project. I dont think it will be work. and maybe you have to remove 'router.refresh()' because refresh deletes all data.

Comment: The problem is that it not reaching the api end point.i tried my api on postman it could find the local host.i also removed router refresh still same

Answer (score 0):

The issue is on how you are setting the data after making the call, in your code you are declaring the data inside the try and catch and using it outside the try and catch. Basically meaning you are reassigning your data to itself:

1. Declare the data outside the data try and catch
2. Use response instead of data:

   const response = await fetch('/api/about', {
   method: 'POST',
   body: formData,
   });
3. Then assign response to data setData(respone)

Full code will look similar to this:

```
import { Button, Input, Textarea } from "@nextui-org/react";
import React, { FormEvent, useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router"; 

const adminAbout = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [data, setData] = useState(null); 

  async function handleSubmit(e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const formData = new FormData(e.currentTarget);
      const response = await fetch('/api/about', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
      });
      if (response.ok) {
        const responseData = await response.json();
        setData(responseData);
        router.refresh();
      } else {
        console.error("Request failed with status:", response.status);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("An error occurred during the process:", error);
    }
  }
  return (
    <section className="mx-auto py-10 p-5 flex flex-col max-w-lg">
      <div className="">
        <h1 className="py-5 font-bold">About Form</h1>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Input name="name" placeholder="Name" />
          <Textarea name="description" placeholder="Description" />
          <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};
export default adminAbout;
```